# Unrecognized Datepicker

Tags: angularjs, uwp

[image: Need help identifying which date picker is this or where the style is set]

I am running a UWP app which shows this fancy date picker on my Touchscreen laptop.

It is running an angularjs with only bootstrap style. No other libraries.

Anyone recognize this?

Comment: It's the standard built-in UWP/Microsoft Edge date picker: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/date-picker

Comment: @JoeClay Thank you. That is it.